# Перехват и автоматическая прокрутка страницы

Tags: javascript, jquery, прокрутка

Есть длинная страница, где много контента. Страница разбита по секциям, типа лендинг. В теле страницы, при ее прокрутке есть блок высотой 100% экрана. Так вот: возможно ли сделать так, чтобы при прокрутке страницы, как только этот блок попадал в видимую часть экрана, страница автоматически прокручивалась до верха этого блока? Что-то типа скролла страницы по секциям. Вот мне нужно, чтобы этот принцип срабатывал только для одного блока/секции на этой странице. Целый плагин для этого не нужен, да он и не подходит. На странице имеется скрипт модальных окон (их на странице много с большим контентом), он же и перестает корректно работать с подобными плагинами, а именно не корректно работает скроллинг, что очевидно. Поэтому такой эффект нужен только для фрагмента страницы. Благодарю за помощь!

Написал скрипт, но он не работает. В чем может быть ошибка? Поправьте, пожалуйста.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if(document.body.scrollTop === 0) {
        $('#anchor')
$('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $('#anchor').offset().top}, 2000);
      return false;});
    }
});
```

Comment: А что не получается? Логически вы все правильно описали. Нужно на событие мыши `scroll` повесить проверку — виден ли блок. Если да — сделать прокрутку до этого блока.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

плагин: при появлении блока с низу или с верху окна по окончании скрола, страница автоматически прокручивается до верха этого блока. подберите если нужно параметр pause 50 - 350

```js
 $(function(){
(function($) {
$.fn.blockInheart = function(speed, pause) {
    function vis(el) {
        var top = $(el).offset().top,
            height = $(window).height(),
            scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
        return scroll > top - height && scroll < top + height
    }
    this.each(function(indx, el) {
        var hide = true,
            timer;
        $(window).scroll(function() {
            window.clearTimeout(timer);
            if (!vis(el)) hide = true;
            timer = window.setTimeout(function(event) {
                if (vis(el) && hide) $("body, html").animate({
                    scrollTop: $(el).offset().top
                }, speed, function() {
                    hide = false
                })
            }, pause)
        })
    });
    return this
}
})(jQuery);
 $(".hot").blockInheart(800,300)
   })
```

```css
  html,
  body {
    height: 100%;
  }
  .hot {
    border: 1px dashed Gray;
    padding: 5px;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100px;
    margin: 500px auto;
    background-color: rgb(30, 144, 255);
  }
  .hot:nth-of-type(2) {
    background-color: rgb(220, 20, 60);
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
scrollUp
<div class="hot">1</div>
<div class="hot">2</div>
```

Comment: @LADYX  смотрите новый вариант